How to Log Training Loss at Step Zero in Hugging Face Trainer or SFT Trainer?
I'm using the Hugging Face Trainer (or SFTTrainer) for fine-tuning, and I want to log the training loss at step 0 (before any training steps are executed). I know there's an eval_on_start option for evaluation, but I couldn't find a direct equivalent for training loss logging at the beginning of training.
Is there a way to log the initial training loss at step zero (before any updates) using Trainer or SFTTrainer? Ideally, I'd like something similar to eval_on_start.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Solution 1: Custom Callback
I implemented a custom callback to log the training loss at the start of training:
from transformers import TrainerCallback

class TrainOnStartCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def on_train_begin(self, args, state, control, logs=None, **kwargs):
        # Log training loss at step 0
        logs = logs or {}
        logs["train/loss"] = None  # Replace None with an initial value if available
        logs["train/global_step"] = 0
        self.log(logs)

    def log(self, logs):
        print(f"Logging at start: {logs}")
        wandb.log(logs)

# Adding the callback to the Trainer
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    args=training_args,
    optimizers=(optimizer, scheduler),
    callbacks=[TrainOnStartCallback()],
)

This works but feels a bit overkill. It logs metrics at the start of training before any steps.
Solution 2: Manual Logging
Alternatively, I manually log the training loss before starting training:
wandb.log({"train/loss": None, "train/global_step": 0})
trainer.train()

Question:
Are there any built-in features in Trainer or SFTTrainer to log training loss at step zero? Or is a custom callback or manual logging the best solution here? If so, are there better ways to implement this functionality? similar to the eval_on_start but train_on_start?
cross:

discuss.huggingface
github/huggingface


ref: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/34981

what about: logging_first_step?         logging_first_step (bool, *optional*, defaults to False):             Whether to log the first global_step or not.

hf post: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-log-training-loss-at-step-zero-in-hugging-face-trainer-or-sft-trainer/128188

When using huggingface transformer library, the output returned by the model includes the model loss. Before starting the training, simply perform a forward pass on the dataset and obtain the model loss.
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs, labels=labels)

loss = outputs.loss
print(f"Loss: {loss.item()}")


what about: logging_first_step?         logging_first_step (bool, *optional*, defaults to False):             Whether to log the first global_step or not.
